# How to make an image overflow its background in y while respecting everything else?

Tags: css, flexbox

Exploring what's possible with CSS. I'd like to achieve an effect where:

- I have a full-width color background stripe
- The actual content is centered with a fixed width
- The content consists of a paragraph with an image to the right
- The image's top-right sits at its expected place inside the stripe, but its bottom extends below the background stripe

The below achieves this result, but it depends on explicitly setting the inner flex height to 110px and I'm hoping I can instead just have it hug the <p> while not hugging the image div.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; background-color: hsl(215, 100%, 86%); ">
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 500px; height: 110px;">
    <p style="width: 30ch;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <div>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could position the image absolute - but then you would have trouble keeping the content that _follows_ this component at its correct position. There isn't much of an option to have it "fully dynamic", I suppose.

Comment: So you don't want to set a fixed height to the container but still you want this same result where the image is vertically overflown from that horizontal container? Is it your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the image's container be absolutely positioned with `top`, `right` set to `0` with respect to its parent.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; background-color: hsl(215, 100%, 86%); ">
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 500px; position: relative;">
    <p style="width: 30ch;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two changes are, make the immediate parent `position: relative` so it becomes the reference for the absolute positioning and style the image container itself: `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the subtlety around the `position: absolute`, that it only pays attention to parents if they're relative or absolute.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
        <div style="background-color: hsl(215, 100%, 86%); padding: 0 30px;">
            <div
                style="
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    width: 100%;
                "
            >
                <div
                    style="
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        justify-content: center;
                        flex: 1;
                    "
                >
                    <p style="width: 30ch">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                        magna aliqua.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/150" alt="image" style="height: 100%" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I attaching your code. Hope your success.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- "The image's top-right sits at its expected place inside the stripe, but its bottom extends below the background stripe", it's because you have given height to this div:

- Remove the height from div.
- Give width and height to div that you use as img container.
- And set width of img to 100%
- If you need the text to be centered, give card class: align-items: center;
  Hope this will help. :)

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: hsl(215, 100%, 86%);
}

.card {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:500px;
}

.card__desc {
  width:300px;
}

.card__img {
  width: 150px;
  height:150px;
  margin: 0;
}

.card__img img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <p class="card__desc">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <figure class="card__img">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/150">
    </d>
  </div>
</div>
```